# Find last business day of the week in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

We can do the following to get the last Business Day of the month:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CBMonthEnd
from datetime import datetime, date

last_busday_month = BMonthEnd().rollforward(current_date).date()
```

Or with custom holiday calendar:

```
last_busday_month = CBMonthEnd(holidays=holidays).rollforward(current_date).date()
```

How can I achieve the same for the last business day of the week?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the date of the Friday from the same week as the input date, or are you trying to replicate the ability to exclude specific holidays, etc?

Comment: Also, if the input date is a Saturday or Sunday, are you considering one or both of those days to be the end of the week and expecting to output the previous Friday? Or, are you considering one or both of those weekend days to be the beginning of the week?

Comment: Just the same as BMonthEnd but for weekly frequency. I do not understand your question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

# Given the monday on the week that you would to get the last business day
monday='2020-04-06'
t=pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp(end_date), 
pd.Timestamp(end_date)+pd.Timedelta('7 days'),freq='W-MON')
last_day_on_week = t[-1]-pd.offsets.BDay(1)
print (last_day_on_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as neat as pandas methods, but this one works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

from datetime import datetime
from pandas.tseries import offsets
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar


def check_holidays(start_of_week, end_of_week, holidays ):
    if end_of_week in holidays:
        if end_of_week == start_of_week:
            print('There are no business days this week')
            return None

        end_of_week = (end_of_week - offsets.Day(1))
        end_of_week = check_holidays(start_of_week, end_of_week, holidays)
    return end_of_week


def BWeekEnd(current_date, holidays=None, friday=4, startdate='2019-01-01', enddate='2019-12-31'):
    current_date = datetime.strptime(current_date.isoformat()[:10], '%Y-%m-%d')  # round time to 00:00:00
    start_of_week  = (current_date - offsets.Day(current_date.weekday(), normalize=True))
    end_of_week = (current_date + offsets.Day(friday - current_date.weekday(), normalize=True))

    if not holidays:
        cal = calendar()
        holidays = cal.holidays(start=startdate, end=enddate)

    end_of_week = check_holidays(start_of_week, end_of_week, holidays)

    if end_of_week:
        return end_of_week.date()
    else:
        return None


current_date = datetime.today()
BWeekEnd(current_date, holidays=[pd.to_datetime('2019-03-01'), 
                                 pd.to_datetime('2019-02-28'), 
                                 pd.to_datetime('2019-02-27'), 
                                 pd.to_datetime('2019-02-26'),
                                 pd.to_datetime('2019-02-25')])
```